# Running Kafka Connect With S3 Sink on Docker/ECS is not producing to S3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run Kafka Connect with s3 sink(read from Kafka and write to S3) on Elastic Container Service.

Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest
WORKDIR /etc/kafka-connect
COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY kafka-connect.properties .
COPY s3-sink.properties .
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:latest
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars
CMD /etc/kafka-connect/entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
PROPERTIES_FILE="/etc/kafka-connect/kafka-connect.properties"
S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE="/etc/kafka-connect/s3-sink.properties"
sed -i "s|KAFKA_USERNAME|$KAFKA_USERNAME|g" $PROPERTIES_FILE
sed -i "s|KAFKA_PASSWORD|$KAFKA_PASSWORD|g" $PROPERTIES_FILE

sed -i "s|AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID|$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID|g" $CONSOLE_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE
sed -i "s|AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY|$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY|g" $CONSOLE_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE

/usr/bin/connect-distributed $PROPERTIES_FILE $S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE
```

kafka-connect.properties contains the following keys

```
name=abc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=topicName

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
group.id=myGroupId
bootstrap.servers=bootstrapServer:9091,...
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="KAFKA_USERNAME" password="KAFKA_PASSWORD";
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO

offset.storage.topic=test-offsets-topic
config.storage.topic=test-config-topic
status.storage.topic=test-status-topic
```

KAFKA_USERNAME and KAFKA_PASSWORD are being substituted in entrypoint.sh via environment variables.

s3-sink.properties

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
s3.bucket.name=bucket-name
s3.region=eu-west-2
s3.part.size=5242880
aws.access.key.id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws.secret.access.key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
```

Similarly AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are being substituted via env variables.

However, when the connect runs, I do not see anything getting produced to the s3 bucket despite there being lots of traffic in the topic. What am I doing wrong?
No errors in the CloudWatch logs, just see this info message

````
[2024-01-09 23:10:27,086] INFO These configurations '[connector.class, config.storage.topic, tasks.max, topics, group.id, status.storage.topic, value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy, value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source, key.converter.schemas.enable, schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source, name, value.converter.schemas.enable, offset.storage.topic, value.converter, key.converter, key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source]' were supplied but are not used yet. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:378)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Certain configuration were missing from Kafka Consumer properties. These properties need to be defined separately for Consumer and the Sink connector. Also the sink connector needs to be started/registered once the Kafka Connect has started successfully.

connect-distributed-custom.properties

```
group.id=producer-my-group-id
bootstrap.servers=KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="KAFKA_USERNAME" password="KAFKA_PASSWORD";
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter

offset.storage.topic=test-offsets-topic
config.storage.topic=test-config-topic
status.storage.topic=test-status-topic

plugin.path=/usr/share/confluent-hub-components

consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="KAFKA_USERNAME" password="KAFKA_PASSWORD";
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:7.5.3

WORKDIR /etc/kafka

COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY connect-distributed-custom.properties .
COPY s3-sink.json .


# Expose the REST API port
EXPOSE 8083:8083
EXPOSE 9092:9092

CMD /etc/kafka/entrypoint.sh
```

s3-sink.json

```
{
  "name": "s3-sink-test",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "topicName",
    "s3.region": "eu-west-2",
    "s3.bucket.name": "test-kafka-connect",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "name": "s3-sink-test",
    "flush.size": "100",
    "topics.dir": "kafka-topics-5",
    "consumer.override.auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",

    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",

    "basic.auth.user.info": "SCHEMA_AUTH",
    "schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "SCHEMA_AUTH",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "SCHEMA_AUTH",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "SCHEMA_AUTH",

    "schema.registry.url": "SCHEMA_REGISTRY",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "SCHEMA_REGISTRY",

    "basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",


    "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy":  "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"deadLetterQueueTopic",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
    "locale": "en",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "timestamp.extractor": "Record",
    "partition.duration.ms": "300000",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "300000"
  }
}
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PROPERTIES_FILE="/etc/kafka/connect-distributed-custom.properties"

S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE="/etc/kafka/s3-sink.json"

sed -i "s|KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS|$KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS|g" $PROPERTIES_FILE
sed -i "s|KAFKA_USERNAME|$KAFKA_USERNAME|g" $PROPERTIES_FILE
sed -i "s|KAFKA_PASSWORD|$KAFKA_PASSWORD|g" $PROPERTIES_FILE

sed -i "s|SCHEMA_REGISTRY|$SCHEMA_REGISTRY|g" $S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE

sed -i "s|SCHEMA_AUTH|$SCHEMA_AUTH|g" $S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE

confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:10.5.7

/usr/bin/connect-distributed $PROPERTIES_FILE &
sleep 60


echo "===Creating Connector===="

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @"$S3_SINK_PROPERTIES_FILE" http://localhost:8083/connectors

echo "===Done Creating Connector===="

tail -f /dev/null
```